# How to persist the workflow from a CodeActivity or NativeActivity?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have an activity, and would like to save the state (persist) the workflow so its state will save to the database.  Can you please show me or redirect me how this may happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Persist activity in the toolbox under Runtime.

I don't think you can Persist from inside an activity as the workflow must be in a persist-able state before it can persist.

I prefer to set `_workflowApplication.PersistableIdle = WorkflowApplicationPersistableIdle;`

Then put in a Delay activity where you want to trigger the Persist.  The advantage is that you can do stuff in `WorkflowApplicationPersistableIdle()`. 
e.g

```
        private PersistableIdleAction WorkflowApplicationPersistableIdle(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_canWeUnloadThisWorkflow)
        {
            _workflowController.RemoveWFManagerFromList(this);
            return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
        }
        return PersistableIdleAction.None;
    }
```